# In React, how can a parent change prop or state values on another component programatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created and rendered another component. On a button click, I want to do some calculations and then change some props on that other component so it will update its view. How would I do this?

If they need to be state values instead of props, that's ok. Can the `setState()` be called from another component?

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {

    other: null,

    constructor(props, children)
    {
        //Create the component
        this.other = ReactDOM.render( otherReactElement, document.body );
    }

...

    //An on Click handler
    handle: function(evt)
    {
        //This is what I want to do
        other.setProps( { aPropToChange: "new value" } );
    }
};
```

The "setProps" is deprecated. What else can I do to enable something like that?

Comment: Can you share a minimum code sample?

Comment: @DavinTryon Added some code.

Comment: What's the context of your `handle` method ? Is it in a React component ? Could you add more detailed "react" code ?

Comment: @Pcriulan Updated the code

Comment: What you're trying to do is very weird. Why are you rendering with ReactDOM inside the constructor of another component ?

Comment: @Pcriulan I'm actually not. I'm rendering on return from getting data from the server, but I thought this was simpler. The important question is how do I update either props or state on that "other"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass new props to `other`, you have to call `ReactDOM.render()` again with the new props as you can see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#new-deprecations-introduced-with-a-warning).

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/51797/)  where you can see how to update the `props` and the `state` correctly.

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.other = ReactDOM.render( <Hello name="World"/>, document.getElementById('otherComponent') );
    }
    changeState(evt)
    {
        this.other.setState({lastName: "setState works"})
    }
    changeProps(evt){
        this.other = ReactDOM.render( <Hello name="New Name" /> , document.getElementById('otherComponent') );
    }
    render(){
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.changeState.bind(this)}>Change state</button>
            <button onClick={this.changeProps.bind(this)}>Change props</button>
            </div>
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. The `changeProps` - I couldn't just change one prop, I'd have to override all of them, correct? Since it's fully re-rendering?

Comment: Yep, it overrides the props, the `state` is preserved though. You can pass the old props using something like this https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/51796/

Answer (score 1):

In React, a parent component can change the state of its child component using refs. Using refs, you get a reference to the child component and you can use that reference to invoke a function inside a child component and that function can have the setState() call inside it.

You can read more about react refs here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute

Comment: Why would I need refs if I already have the component returned from `ReactDOM.render`?

Comment: @DonRhummy In this case, you have the component returned from ReactDOM.render, but in general use case, the child elements may be rendered inside a parent element like this: <Parent><Child/></Parent>. In that case if you have a ref to Child like  <Parent><Child ref="childref" /></Parent>, you can invoke the Child's function in parent using  this.refs.childref.childFunction().